# Mongo Query to convert "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z" to YYYY-mm-dd

Tags: mongodb

I need to convert a date to a format   "Mon Oct 17 09:00:00 IST 2016" to 2016-10-17

my query is like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $project: { yearMonthDayUTC: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date:new Date("Mon Oct 17 09:00:00 IST 2016") } } } }] )
```

How can I achieve that through a mongo query
Kindly help me.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: @BlackBeard my query is like this db.collection.aggregate(    [      {        
$project: {          
 yearMonthDayUTC: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date:new Date("Mon Oct 17 09:00:00 IST 2016") } }        
}      
}] )    returning ("1970-01-01") every time irrespective of bson string date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use "dateToString" in aggregate also check [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

Ex: **$date** is Your Date to Convert.

```
db.Collection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project: {
          yearMonthDayUTC: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } }
       }
     }
   ]
)
```

Comment: I tried this..that's giving an error FYI  i'm assuming this  "Mon Oct 17 09:00:00 IST 2016" as string but not an ISODate and i want to convert this string to date YYYY-mm-dd

Comment: The error message is  "errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type string to Date",

Comment: First Covert To Date using  "new Date("Mon Oct 17 09:00:00 IST 2016")" than formate date using "$dateToString"

Comment: But when i try doing aggregate with java driver it is giving Bad Request

Comment: Look like its java problem. Please provide exact error so easy to help.

Comment: when  i try to execute aggregate in java,server is throwing Bad Request error..Nothing more than that

Comment: hey @IftekharDani,when i use $dateToString every time it is returning "1970-01-01"